# Phonegap How to log down some variable for debug use in Eclipse?

Tags: android, cordova

I have try to use console.log() or console.log(username)
But I don't see anything special in logcat.
How can I debug for some easy variable checking.

Comment: Normally, I use alert() or document.write() to detect value of data

Comment: console.log should work... Try console.log("Username = "+username); Then you can see what exactly is going on. Because if username variable null then it wont show in the log cat

Comment: filter log cat with the tag Web Console. there you may get all the outputs related to your phonegap project.